# Pythonic method of pulling multiple arrays out of a dictionary and stacking them with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I have a dictionary that has arrays in them. I'd like to grab those arrays out with numpy and stack them using np.dstack and I cannot figure how.
The dictionary format is shown below minus the nxx of course. Additionally, I'm showing the nx numbers in a sequence, and while the dictionary contains a keys n1, n2 up to the highest nvalue, they are not actually in a sequence.

```
{'n0': masked_array, 'n1': masked_array, 'n2': masked_array, ..., 'nxx': masked_array}
```

The data for each pair is displayed as

```
'n0': masked_array(
  data=[[0.13530391454696655, 0.26814308762550354, 0.26814308762550354,
         ..., --, --, --],
        [0.21222707629203796, 0.22386012971401215, 0.19620446860790253,
         ..., --, --, --],
        [0.22701908648014069, 0.23818181455135345, 0.23777709901332855,
         ..., --, --, --],
        ...,
        [--, --, --, ..., --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, ..., --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, ..., --, --, --]],
  mask=[[False, False, False, ...,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False, ...,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False, ...,  True,  True,  True],
        ...,
        [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]],
  fill_value=-inf,
  dtype=float32)
```

Specifying the a print of each entity using

```
print(arraydict['n0'])
```

provides

```
[[0.13530391454696655 0.26814308762550354 0.26814308762550354 ... -- --
  --]
 [0.21222707629203796 0.22386012971401215 0.19620446860790253 ... -- --
  --]
 [0.22701908648014069 0.23818181455135345 0.23777709901332855 ... -- --
  --]
 ...
 [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]]
```

So if they were individual variables I'd be able to do something like (following the n order is important)

```
arraystack = np.dstack((n0, n1, n2, n3, ..., nxx, ))
```

I cannot for the life of me conceptualize how to use np.dstack to pull and stack each from the dictionary starting with n0 onwards as

```
arraystack = np.dstack(([arraydict[key] for key in arraydict]))
```

does seems to work, but it does not seem to maintain the n0, n1, n2, n3 sequence.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? For older versions of python (where indeed dictionaries don't preserve the order of entries), I would go for either an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) or for sorting the keys, e.g. `[arraydict[key] for key in sorted(arraydict.keys())]`.

Comment: If you simply need to extract the `data` array, foreach `masked_array` - how about this then? `np.dstack([x.data for x in arraydict.values()])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
arraystack = np.dstack([arraydict['n'+str(i)] for i in range(len(arraydict))])
```

This will make sure that the order is preserved.

Comment: Oh man, this is golden, it works perfectly. Now I need to figure out how to add a separate array into arraystack with the same command.

"arraystack = np.dstack([arraydict['n'+str(i)] for i in range(len(arraydict))], separray)"

Doesn't seem like the right format, but I'll figure it out.

Comment: arraystack = np.dstack([arraydict['n'+str(i)] for i in range(len(arraydict))] + [separray])
should work for that.

Comment: You're a champ. Thanks a massive ton.